# Flex-box ignores wrapped children's margin (margin collapse)

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">B</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS (prefix free):

```
.outer {
  display: box;
  box-orient: vertical;

  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height:     50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

[image: A and B]

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/boennemann/pen/oFwtK).

`A` is wrapped in a `<div>` so it's margin gets ignored.

**Q: How can I achieve `B`'s behavior for `A` (margin) with the flex box model?**

Note: The div wrappers can go multiple levels deep

Targeting: latest Chrome/Safari/iOS

Thank you very much for your help!

Edit: Thanks to @JoséCabo I came up with this:

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height:     50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/boennemann/pen/CLyot)

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Safari:
[image: Safari]

Unfortunately it doesn't work in Safari as mentioned by @cimmanon, so I still need some help.

Comment: Did you know that box API is deprecated? You have to use display: flex; api instead.

Comment: Which is the result do you want to get? Sorry, but I don't understand you.

Comment: @JoséCabo The properties that should be used *greatly* depends on which browser you're targeting.  Safari, for instance, follows one of the older specs.

Comment: @JoséCabo the second result (B) is the desired one, but it should work with those div wrappers in between `.outer` and `.inner` as in (A). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I came up with the right solution (for my specific problem).

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/boennemann/pen/weLAI)

I'm using `display: inline-block` on `.inner` to disable margin collapsing and then compensate for the lost width with `width: 100%`.

All the credit goes to [cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057840/) for pointing me in the right "margin collapse" direction

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking at actually has nothing to do with Flexbox, but what's called *margin collapse*

```
.outer div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

The addition of the border has prevented the margin from collapsing.  Rather than relying on margins, I would recommend placing a padding on the parent container:

```
.outer {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #eef;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -1em;
}
  
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  min-width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>item</div>
    <div class='item'>item</div>
    <div class='item'>item</div>   
    <div class='item'>item</div>
    <div class='item'>item</div>
    <div class='item'>item</div>    
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, to cover all of your prefixes, you need something like this:

```
.outer {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I still look for my perfect solution where I can keep using the margin on `.inner`. Ideally I'd like to make changes to `.inner` only. But the *margin collapse* thing is sth. I can build upon. Thank you very much!