# Flexbox lost width of flex items in FF and Opera

Tags: flexbox

I carefully read [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057411/flex-box-ignores-wrapped-childrens-margin-margin-collapse)

and this article in [csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

and tried to use all prefix to make my layout working in modern browsers, but its working only in Chrome. In other browsers flex items lost flex value (width). I cant understand whats the matter.
I am greatly appriciate and help and advice! Thank you!
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/usisic/24/edit)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>nested flex</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>Привет мир!</header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item1">red</div>
    <div class="item_nested">
    <div class="b">blue</div>
    <div class="c">green</div>
  </div>
    </div>
  <footer>Прощай мир!</footer>

</body>
</html>



.wrap { 
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; 
  -moz-box-orient: horisontal;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
   max-width: 1200px;
}
.item1 { 
   width: 70%;                     /* No flex here, 
  -moz-box-flex: 1;               /* OLD - Firefox 19- */

  background: #eee;
}
.b { 
  background: #ddd; height:50%;

}
.c { 
  background: #ccc; height:50%;
}
.item_nested {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;            /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;               /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  width: 20%;                     /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
  -webkit-flex: 1;                /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;                    /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                        /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrap {-moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
  .wrap > .a, .wrap > .item_nested {width: auto;} 
  .b.c {
    height:auto;
  }

    .item1 { 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

}

Comment: I understand that Chrome might have the behavior you're looking for, but it looks like it might be the one behaving inappropriately.  It's making all sorts of assumptions about how tall certain elements should be when no explicit height is provided.

Comment: Thank you for answer! In chrome its complitely okey. but i have problem with width in other browsers. What can i do to solve this? i cant set up the width that i  want

Comment: This is about as close as I could get it for both Opera and Chrome:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/tuDrA.  Unless you're taking advantage of wrapping (which excludes Firefox and any other browser using the "box" spec), you aren't getting much benefit from Flexbox, at least not for this layout.